# Android Studio - Using Hashmap to sum declared int of strings

Tags: java, android, string, hashmap, integer

Right, so my problem is that I have 18 spinners (units) which all use the same string array for "Select Grade, Pass, Merit, Distinction" and I would like "Pass, Merit, Distinction" to equal 70, 80, 90 respectively so I can sum the 18 values up and then display this value in a textview called "yourResults". I have currently used Hashmap to declare that Pass = 70 etc like so:

```
    Button button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.savegrades);
    final Map<String,Integer> gradeScoreMap = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
    gradeScoreMap.put("Pass",70);
    gradeScoreMap.put("Merit",70);
    gradeScoreMap.put("Distinction",70);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public int getNumber(String text)
        {
            return gradeScoreMap.get(text);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int score;
            {
                score = getNumber(Grade_Spinner1.toString());
                yourResult.setText(score);
            }
```

Currently my code only sees Grade_Spinner1 which is the first spinner as a test.

I would like a button to sum the total of all 18 units and then display this sum in the textview but I can't currently get the textview to display the first spinner value. I should also mention that this code is in a fragment.

Any guidance/help along with explanations as I'm new to android studio and java would be very helpful and appreciated. :)

Comment: Clarify: did you say you have 18 individual spinners in your layout?

Comment: Yes, each spinner represents a unit (eg unit 1 - ecommerce) of a school/college course. A different spinner also changes this between 12 or 18 depending on the choice of the user. This spinner is on a previous fragment and I can provide the code for that.

Answer (score 0):

When button clicked you should get selected items of spinners of interest and then the value which corresponds to the your hashmap(gradeScoreMap) via getNumber(text) and add all the values to get final score.

```
    Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    Spinner spinner3 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
    Spinner spinner4 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner4);
            .
            .
            .



 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {

 public int getNumber(String text)
        {
            return gradeScoreMap.get(text);
        }


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int score=0;
            {
              String text1 = spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString();  
              String text2 = spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString();  
              String text3 = spinner3.getSelectedItem().toString();  
              String text4 = spinner4.getSelectedItem().toString();  

            score = getNumber(text1)+getNumber(text2)+getNumber(text3)
                   +getNumber(text4)+.....;

              yourResult.setText(String.valueOf(score));
            }

        }
   }
```

Comment: what is the crash? Please post your logcat

Comment: I've figured it, I haven't made a Hashmap for selectgrade

Comment: Could you maybe describe how I might alter this code to allow for a sum to occur between different two spinners whose values are both Pass/70 please. :)

Comment: There are several ways of doing this and one is as given by @Eenvincible

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:

- If all your spinners are visible as expected;
- Attach an interface to listen for item selection : `OnItemSelectedListener
- Now, since you have 18 of them, in each spinner, you need to do something when something is selected.
- You have the **prompt, pass, merit, distinction** possibilities. It means if someone doesn't select a value in each spinner, you want to actually stop and show an error message.
- Now the important part is this: `switch(selectedItem)`and check for the `pass merit distinction`values. This will allow you to assign to your 18 spinners their final selections. Simply keep 18 class level private variables that will store your answers.
- Before moving on to the next view for instance, just make sure you have validated the final data!!

I hope this makes sense and helps you!

**In summary**
When an item is selected from a given spinner, set a value for that particular item in your class level variable (18 of them - 1 for each spinner).
At the end, each variable will contain a value from the selection. But remember to switch between the 3 possible options for each spinner!

Good luck!

**EDIT**

---

You have stated above that a **pass** represents a certain value like 70 and **merit** represents 80 and **distinction** represents 90;

Now if you think about it, it means to get 80 as the corresponding value of the score, a user will have to select **merit**. So to arrive at 80, you have to know that the user selected merit. How do you know that in Java? You can use `if statements` or `switch statement`. Like this inside your onItemSelectedListener of each spinner:

```
switch(arrayOfStringValues[position]){
    case "pass":
         someUnitXScore = 70;
         break;
    case "merit":
         someUnitXScore = 80;
         break;
    case "distinction":
         someUnitXScore = 90;
         break;
}
```

`But always remember to capture the first value which is the prompt!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It mostly makes sense but what does switch mean (I assume my switch between 12 and 18 units)  and why private variables and not public?

Comment: I've figured a very long way of adding the values together but it works. I have used a sum of score 1 through 18 and each score code is score = getnumber(text1) etc...again very long but it works for 18 units.

Comment: You actually want if(sum <= 1480){}

Comment: No problem; I wish my answer was helpful!